# CMAKE creating an additional directory in the build file

Tags: c++, cmake

My current project structure looks like this:

```
Project
      --src/
           --CMakeLists.txt 
           --Graph.cpp
           --Graph.hpp
           --main.cpp
      --build/
      --CMakeLists.txt
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in the Project folder lookalike this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(GRAPHTHEORY VERSION 1.0.0)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

the CMakeLists.txt in src file looks like this:

```
add_library(Graph Graph.hpp Graph.cpp)

add_executable(graph_theory main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(graph_theory PRIVATE Graph )
```

When I go into the `build/` directory, and run `cmake ..` and then `make`, the executable `graph_theory` is in a new `src/` directory within `build`

I am not sure why a new `src/` directory is being created in my `build/' directory.

Edit:

So what I was trying to do is replicate running

`cmake -S src/ -B build/` from Project directory.

When I do the above and then `cd` into `build/` and then run `make`, the executable is created in `build/` directory.

Comment: it holds the build files related to the source files in the src directory?

Comment: @user253751 is there a way for the executable to appear in the build directory directly? I mean so what I am describing is expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build artifacts and cache is kept in a directory that reflect the subdirectory you added in CMake with the `add_subdirectory` command.

However, you can change where the final target end up by changing the default value of `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. For example, this code will put it in the `bin` directory:

```
set_target_properties(graph_theory
PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added some additional info and the reason why I was doing this in the first place.